# Export Result from Command dd to Output File

Tags: linux, command, rhel

I am having trouble to export result to output file from the following command for speed test,

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=1048576 | ssh root@10.99.1.1 'cat > /dev/null'
```

I have tried,

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=1048576 | ssh root@10.99.1.1 'cat > /dev/null' >> result.txt
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=1048576 | ssh root@10.99.1.1 'cat > /dev/null' >> result.txt 2>&1
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=1048576 | ssh root@10.99.1.1 'cat > /dev/null' 2>> result.txt
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024 count=1048576 | ssh root@10.99.1.1 'cat > /dev/null' | tee -a result.txt 2>&1
```

result.txt was created but it's empty.

I guess I am having trouble of pipeline.

Thank you!
Philip

Comment: Try `dd ... 2 >> result.txt | ssh ...`

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Why are you using `root` if you're writing to `/dev/null`? Any user can write to this, you don't need upgraded privileges.